# Warning: Attempt to present FBSDKContainerViewController - iOS 9 Facebook SDK 4.6

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I updated the Facebook to 4.6 sdk. Now I am getting this warning when the app try to present facebook permission prompt for the second time (I want to prompt facebook permission window again, if the user denied to give access to get his/her email address)

this My warning :

```
Warning: Attempt to present <FBSDKContainerViewController: 0x7ff085073760> on <TabBarController: 0x7ff083899c00> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

It was working well in the previous versions. That means, if the user un select email permission in the first time, my app prompt the permission window again.

Please help me on this issue

Answer (score 0):

If you are requesting for permissions, you can pass nil to determine the visible view controller

```
facebookLoginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["email"], fromViewController: nil) {
```